# How to remove the parenthesis and a comma in the output

Tags: python

I am writing a program in python for a banking application using arrays and functions. Here's my code:

```
NamesArray=[]
AccountNumbersArray=[]
BalanceArray=[]
def PopulateAccounts():
    for position in range(5):
        name = input("Please enter a name: ")
        account = input("Please enter an account number: ")
        balance = input("Please enter a balance: ")
        NamesArray.append(name)
        AccountNumbersArray.append(account)
        BalanceArray.append(balance)
def SearchAccounts():
    accounttosearch = input("Please enter the account number to search: ")
    for position in range(5):
        if (accounttosearch==AccountNumbersArray[position]):
            print("Name is: " +NamesArray[position])
            print(NamesArray[position],"account has the balance of: ",(BalanceArray[position]))
            break
    if position>4:
        print("The account number not found!")


while True:
    print("**** MENU OPTIONS ****")
    print("Type P to populate accounts")
    print("Type S to search for account")
    print("Type E to exit")
    choice = input("Please enter your choice: ")
    if (choice=="P"):
        PopulateAccounts()
    elif (choice=="S"):
        SearchAccounts()
    elif (choice=="E"):
        print("Thank you for using the program.")
        print("Bye")
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid choice. Please try again!")
```

Everything is fine now, but when I run the program and search for an account. For example, when I search an account the output shows `('name', 'account has the balance of: ', 312)` instead of `name account has the balance of: 312` How do I fix this?

Comment: At a guess, you're actually using Python 2.x. Step 1: upgrade. Step 2: [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: `print(NamesArray[position]+"account has the balance of: "+str((BalanceArray[position])))

Comment: `    print(' '.join([NamesArray[position],"account has the balance of: ",BalanceArray[position]]))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the line

```
print(NamesArray[position],"account has the balance of: ",(BalanceArray[position]))
```

you should use string concatenation to add the different strings. One way to do this would be like this:

```
print(NamesArray[position] + " account has the balance of: " + str(BalanceArray[position]))
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. Do you also know why if I put a position greater than 5 it doesn't print `The account number not found!`? It is supposed to, but doesn't.

Comment: When your position range of PopulateAccounts() is higher and the account which your are searching is at index higher than SearchAccount(), only then print will work. But when both have range of 5 and account is in PopulateAccounts at lower index, then it won't print. When you enter the account at index greater than 4 in PopulateAccounts and then search it will show you the print otherwise there are other cases like error and index out of range happening in the code.  Just use elif statement with if to consider account number not found situations

Answer (score 0):

u are using old python version,
replace your line with this :

```
print(NamesArray[position] + "account has the balance of: " + (BalanceArray[position]))
```

use ' + ' instead of comma

Comment: Do you also know why if I put a position greater than 5 it doesn't print The account number not found!? It is supposed to, but doesn't.